# Как интегрировать Google Sheets с сайтом?

Tags: javascript, php, google-spreadsheet

Как сделать так, чтобы когда пользователь сайта отправлял заявку, данные автоматически заполнялись в Google таблице?

Answer (score 2):

у Google для удобства работы с их сервисами есть возможность писать свои скрипты,
тут можно почитать подробнее:
[статья про Google JS для своих сервисов](https://xakep.ru/2015/01/08/google-apps-script/)

связать их с кодом можно через Google API, почитайте тут:
[документация гугл по API](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/quickstart/php)